# Error while checking ant version

Tags: macos, ant, homebrew

I have used brew to install ant previously. When I run `brew install ant` I get:

```
"Warning: ant-1.9.7 already installed"
```

However if I run `ant -v` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Xms256M
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Xms256M
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

For reference, here is my bash profile:

```
ANT_HOME=/Users/name/Documents
ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME ANT_OPTS PATH

[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

# Enable tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash

# colors
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the issue was because I forgot to add "apache-ant-1.9.7" to the end of the ant location path in my .bash_profile. Eg.

```
ANT_HOME=/Users/MyName/Documents/apache-ant-1.9.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect value set for environment variable `ANT_OPTS`. `-` is forgot / omitted before `Xms256M` instead of `-Xms256M`

Please ensure `ANT_OPTS` has correct value.

For example: Below set both minimum and maximum heap sizes to 256MB.

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx256M"
```

Comment: Hi Rao, thanks for your comment. I was missing the - in that line however adding it in has still not fixed the issue. My .bash file is below for reference:

Comment: Can you please update the question with `env|sort`? And what is the latest error after that change?

Comment: I found the issue, posted it below. Thanks very much for your help though, much appreciated.